# куда попадает файл при загрузке на сайт wordpress

Tags: python, php, wordpress

Имею такой код.Подскажите куда попадет файл при загрузке?

```
upload_file = open('D:/test', 'rb')
payload = MultipartEncoder({'test': upload_file})
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers={'Content-Type': payload.content_type})
```

Comment: Первый же ответ из гугла: `/wp-content/uploads/`

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar - Честно не нашел.Пол дня искал.можете кинуть ссылку?Это временная папка?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/wordpress/papka-wp-content#uploads-mediafajly-i-zagruzki